# What is the best way to use a reagent component in react js?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

Say I have a reagent class with :reagent-render other reagent class/element, how can I convert this and export as a regular react component that can be mounted to regular react application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of Reagent your using, it can vary a bit. If your using 0.5+, look at `reagent.core/as-element`, documented in the [0.5.0 News](https://reagent-project.github.io/news/news050.html) under Simple React Integration. If using 0.6+, the output of `reagent.core/create-class` can be used in JSX directly, as documented in the [0.6.0 Alpha News](https://reagent-project.github.io/news/news060-alpha.html).